# Get Search Engines to link to sub-pages instead of index

Tags: php, html, ruby, seo

I wrote a blogging system from scratch (http://seanhess.net). I have the last 10 posts displayed on the index page `/`, and each post has it's own page `/post/a_simple_post`. I'm getting a good rank in google when I search for specific info from my posts, but google links to the index page instead of the post page. How do I get the search engine to drill into those post links?

```
<div class="blog_post">
    <div class="info">
        <span class="tags">
            <a href="/tag/framework">Framework</a>
            <a href="/tag/php">PHP</a>
            <a href="/tag/tutorial">Tutorial</a>
        </span>     
        <span class="date">August 03, 2009</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1><a href="/posts/example_post">Example Post</a></h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google probably displays your home page because it thinks it is a relevant answer to the search the user did...

One way that would help making your "post" pages more important is to display the full-content of the post on the home page for only the last post ; and, for the next ones, only display some excerpt, or a summary, or something like that.

It would make your post pages more important... But that would also mean having a "less important" home page... Which may or may not be good.

Google also uses links from other websites : if many important sites link to your homepage, and only a few link to your post pages, google will think the home page is more important than those.

As your blog is about PHP, one nice thing could be to be syndicated on http://www.planet-php.net/ : it allows many people to see your blog entries -- and is nice for visibility too *(both to users and to google, as it has a high pagerank, I suppose)*

Still, google is probably already exploring your whole site : if there are links to your post pages *(there are on the home page, at least)*, google will visit thoses one day or another...

One thing I just noticed, though : your first post was in june, and you've been active only for a something like a month and a half ; it is not **that long**, especially if not many websites have links to yours...

In the end, there is only one secret : the more you'll write interesting stuff, the more people will find your blog interesting, the more they'll talk about it and include links to it, the more google will see about it too, the higher you'll be in results, and so on ;-)

*But, yes, it takes time... Especially if you want to only write interesting posts -- and you should not post crap just to have lots of content !*

I just saw you have a first blog on http://code.seanhess.net/ and that you now have another one on http://seanhess.net/ ; do you think it would be wise *(depends on your content, on what you want and all that !)* to move all blog-posts from the first one to the new one, adding permanent redirections on the old pages to the new ones ?

You might also want to take a look at some articles on the net, as well as some questions/answers here on SO, that could give you some useful advices. For instance :

- [Is SEO knowledge important for web developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312347/is-seo-knowledge-important-for-web-developers)
- [Using SEO-friendly links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975240/using-seo-friendly-links)
- [What kind of SEO Technique need to apply for my website…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005320/what-kind-of-seo-technique-need-to-apply-for-my-website)
- [SEO URL Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621380/seo-url-structure)
- and probably lots of others -- provided you know what you are searching for, you'll find lots of interesting "tips/techniques"

And if you search with... google for instance... you might find many interested articles on the net about that too...

Comment: Awesome answers! In terms of moving content -- it's not that I want to be higher so much as I want the link in google to actually take them to the content. There's nothing more annoying that google saying it's indexed useful info but you can't find it on the resulting site

Comment: Thanks :-) That's what I meant by adding permanent redirection : any user (or google) that would try to access your blog-posts by the old URL would automatically be brought to the new URL (only thing they'd see is the URL changed). For more informations, see, for instance : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Moving_a_site_to_a_new_domain

Comment: My old URLs are fine (I mean, I should do what you're saying, but google hits always go to a post). It's the google hits for my new blog that are messed up.  

For example, google "ruby sinatra form." I'm the second hit, but it will take you awhile to find the relevant post. No amount of redirecting my old site is going to fix that. 

That said, everything you said was fabulous advice, and all the ideas presented here should help me to figure something out.

Comment: in this case, having only a short-version of the posts (except for the last one or two, that would get a full-version) on your homepage might help : when your last article is still recent, it is shown on the homepage, and, then, after a while, it's the "post" page that becomes more relevant -- at least, if google does what would seem logical ^^

Comment: And it would get you a smaller homepage : right now, yours is 28 screens longs ! That's really **long** (ok, I'm on my laptop, which only has a 1280x800 screen -- but, still : it is quite too long) -- As a sidenote, I took a look at the size (in KB) of your page, it's light, which is good... but you might want to gzip JS files : some are pretty big... (ok, it's offtopic, I admit)

Answer (score 4):

The search engines already do it, unless your `robots.txt` file specifies otherwise, or some special attributes in your `<a>` tag (which it seems you are not using).

I think the only problem you are having is that your index page ranks much better than your sub-pages. This might be because people link to your index page.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to have a descriptive title tag and meta description in each of the content pages. Google has a useful section and starter guide I refer to frequently on this topic: [Google SEO site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291).

I recently finished this book on SEO which has a lot of useful tips on technique and online tools to help increase search rank: [Kris Jones SEO book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470224487)

What I've seen is the quickest way to move up in search rankings is to get pages linked to from other sites considered to be an authority on the topic the page is focused on.