# PHP: Router Framework, Actually Going to the "pretty" URL

Tags: php, url, router, friendly-url

I have implemented my router framework where I basically use a lookup table to tell what the url will be.

My original urls which had some ugly stuff like domain.com?id=26 for example, will now have: domain.com/words-that-look-nice

But my question is:
If all the pages will be looked up and redirected to, the actual HTML markup will be in 1 file called my_page.php - correct?  The only difference will be that my_page.php will appear differently to the user depending on the item being looked up, correct?

If so, then how do I do this "masking" of the url ??

I mean, once I know what the url will be, how do I make the page my_page.php serve all the data for that particular page that is looked up?

Thanks and sorry if question is convoluted :)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842445/what-is-a-good-way-to-have-a-seo-url-system-built-up-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do first is work out if you can use "rewrites". If you are running apache with "mod_rewrite" then you will be able to use it.

1. Create a .htaccess file in the root directory... domain.com/. 
   Put the following in there:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

1. Now what will happen is that all requests in the form of `"domain.com/this-is-my-page"` are rewritten to the form "domain.com/index.php?r=this-is-my-page"
2. Setup your router to lookup the value of r in the database. Your table would look like this:
   ID | URL
   55 | this-is-my-page
   56 | this-is-my-next-page
3. so run something like `"SELECT ID FROM router WHERE URL=LOWER('{$r}')"`. ofcourse don't forget to check for sql injection attacks.
4. You now have you ID and you can populate the page as you do at the moment.

Hope that helps :)